# Python pandas data cleansing

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to python pandas, I am having difficulty in achieving the below data cleansing, kindly help.

My actual data (csv file link - https://s3.amazonaws.com/rajaampledata/data.csv)

```
Date,Description,Description,Ref. No,Amount,Balance
30/08/2012,TFR-TFR:0000000101-,,,"1,952.50-","4,000.000"
"",Kumar - S/O To:,,,,
"",600010013441,,,,
30/08/2012,FDR-,,,10.50-,"5,114,897.40"
"",AU;541411;301218;RAJA,,,,
"",J;RTGS-AUTO-,,,,
"",TRANSAC,,,,
26/08/2012,DEP-IN162071/D61519,,,"1,000.83","6,100,098.32"
26/08/2012,WDL-IN B CM 20120826,,,180.32-,"789,126.31"
25/08/2012,103-,,,"1,000,000.00","3,225,700.00"
"",IN;112138;100318;BANK,,,,
"",ACC;,,,,
```

I would like to get the data as below

```
30/08/2012,TFR-TFR:0000000101-Kumar - S/O To:600010013441,,,"1,952.50","4,000.000"
30/08/2012,FDR-AU;541411;301218;RAJAJ;RTGS-AUTO-TRANSAC,,,10.50-,"5,114,897.40"
26/08/2012,DEP-IN162071/D61519,,,"1,000.83","6,100,098.32"
26/08/2012,WDL-IN B CM 20120826,,,180.32-,"789,126.31"
25/08/2012,103-IN;112138;100318;BANKACC;,,,"1,000,000.00","3,225,700.00"
```

Comment: add your code please

Comment: Welcome to SO! You probably need to clean your data before loading it into the pandas dataframe. Added my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Try appending to a previous line if the current line starts with a blank. Once you have your data, join them into a string with your comma delimiter.

```
with open('data.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    headers = next(reader)
    lines = []
    for r in reader:
        if r[0] == '':
            lines[-1][1] = lines[-1][1] + r[1]
        else:
            lines.append(r)

lines = [','.join(i) for i in lines]

print(lines)
>>['30/08/2012,TFR-TFR:0000000101-Kumar - S/O To:6.0001E+11,,,1,952.50-,4,000.00',
 '30/08/2012,FDR-AU;541411;301218;RAJAJ;RTGS-AUTO-TRANSAC,,,10.50-,5,114,897.40',
 '26/08/2012,DEP-IN162071/D61519,,,1,000.83,6,100,098.32',
 '26/08/2012,WDL-IN B CM 20120826,,,180.32-,789,126.31',
 '25/08/2012,103-IN;112138;100318;BANKACC;,,,1,000,000.00,3,225,700.00']
```

If you want `headers` read the first line of the csv.

Comment: Hi Thank you very much, working like a charm, kindly advise to how write back to new csv with header, I have tried with pandas, it is coming as 2 columns, first column is row index and second column as full content, instead I want only data separated by comma

Comment: Hi OP! Glad it helped. The writer part will be generally easy with csv module on Python. I would recommend you give it a try before asking, there are plenty of resources for a straight forward task like that. If any of the answers here solved your question, please remember to check them as answers!

Comment: Thank you so much for you help, sure will check